# Hide permanently a class after click using JavaScript (JS) cookies

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, click, hide

Im pretty new in JS and i was wondering how to hide a class after click on it, but i want it remain hidden even if the page is refreshed. I have been doing some reserch i wanted to start with HTML using the "visited" attribute but since the security issues that this bring upon it is impossible to use it. So i check alternatives about using cookies with JS but im not too familiar with it.

The point of all this is to hide a certificate button (that spawns after a quiz completition) once you hit the certificate button to download it.

The html code is this:

```
<a class="ld-certificate-link" target="_self" href="https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/certificates/35472/?course_id=41995&amp;cert-nonce=c0a9e19534" aria-label="Certificado" download=""><span class="ld-icon ld-icon-certificate"></span></a>
```

Im having a hard time with this so i need a little of orientation. Thanks!

UPDATE: Im having a new issue. After i set all the new code it only works once and i have a list of courses with certificates with the same class and i need to every single one of them works even when new ones appear but individualy bc i tryed to do a queryselectorAll and when i pressed one of the classes it hide every single element with the same class but i want to do this individualy. Since the href link of the class is dynamic and unique (As i said before the href spawns after a quiz completition) for every user.
My JS now look a like this:

```js
$('.ld-certificate-link').attr("download","");

document.querySelector('.ld-certificate-link')
.addEventListener("click", handleClick );

function handleClick() {
  alert("i got clicked!");
}

var doShow = localStorage.getItem('.ld-certificate-link');
if (doShow == null) {
  doShow = true;
}
const anchor = document.querySelector('.ld-certificate-link');
if (doShow == "false") {
  anchor.style.display = "none";
}

anchor.addEventListener('click', function() {
  localStorage.setItem('.ld-certificate-link', "false");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to cookies, you can store whether the user has clicked the link in [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), which, just like cookies, stores data locally that persists even after page reload/browser closure.

For example, add a `click` event listener to the anchor and set a key's value to `false`. On page load, check whether the value for the key is `false`, and if so, set the `display` style property of the anchor to `none`.

```js
var doShow = localStorage.getItem("do-show-cert-link");
if (doShow == null) { //the key doesn't exist, this is probably the user's first time visiting
  doShow = true;
}
const anchor = document.querySelector('a');
if (doShow == "false") {
  anchor.style.display = "none";
}

anchor.addEventListener('click', function() {
  localStorage.setItem("do-show-cert-link", "false");
})
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Spectric/yekvx8za/

Comment: Thank you so much! I update my question bc i found another issue in the process but im getting close. Your answer helped me a lot to orientate me on the right way.